# Why antipodal map is homotopic to identity on $S^n$ for $n$ odd and not for $n$ even?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I mean I am imagining that a point on $S^1$ goes to his opposites using maps similar to this [image: homotopy]

but I don't understand

1. if my mental image is right or not
2. what could be the difference between for example  $S^1$ and $S^2$.
   Can you please make a draw for both my questions? I think I'll understand better the explanation and which image I should use for mental process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've done in the case of $S^1$ is the homotopy between the identity map and the rotation, which is the composition of two reflections. However, in case of $S^2$, you need to compose 3 such reflections together. Resulting isometry cannot be represented as a rotation, since it comes from the map of determinant $-1$ (as every reflection has determinant $-1$). It's easy to see that you cannot construct any homotopy between identity and such an isometry that is an isometry for all $F_t$, as the determinant is a continuous function. The proof that there is no such homotopy uses similar tool called a degree of a map, which is an invariant working not only for isometries but all continuous maps $S^n \rightarrow S^n$, but the determinant problem probably solves your concern, why such a homotopy exists only for $S^{2n+1}$. More graphically, the reflection in $\mathbb R^3$ does not lies in $SO(3)$, but in $O(3)^-$, so besides rotating a sphere, you also need to "turn it upside down", and the latter operation cannot be homotoped with the identity without crossing the origin of $\mathbb R^3$, lying outside our sphere.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer there is only one part of the answer"What you've done in the case of S1 is the homotopy between the identity map and **the rotation**" I don't know now if my idea/exercise  was right or not  because i wanted to show homotopy between   identity map and **the inversion** but remaining on S1 so i thought : let's use a rotation . I have got the idea thanks to your answer with the **rotation**

Comment: Yup, but in tnie case the inversion is a rotation. When it is not, as in the case of $\mathbb R^3$, such a homotopy cannot exist on the restriction to sphere - as a homotopy which is linear automorphism for each $t$ cannot change the sign of determinant - so rotations can only be homotoped to different rotations, but not to reflections. Similar reasoning works also without restricting maps to be linear, using degree instead of determinant